# Second beast or the image that will force the people to receive a mark on their hands or forehead in Revelation 13:15-16?

Tags: revelation, prophecy, eschatology

Revelation 13:15-16 NASB

> <sup>**15**</sup> And it was given to him to give breath to the image of the beast, so that the image of the beast would even speak and cause as many as do not worship the image of the beast to be killed. <sup>**16**</sup> And **he** causes all, the small and the great, and the rich and the poor, and the free men and the slaves, to be given a mark on their right hand or on their forehead,

I'm a little bit fazed here, who forces the people to receive the mark on their hand or forehead?

Answer (score 0):

My initial inclination, based on my understanding of the passage, would be to say that it is the image of the beast which enforces the mark.

The first beast is a union of church and state. The second beast arises with neither crown nor worship initially, but later forms an image to the first beast. That is, the second beast has "lamb-like" or Christlike beginnings, but it ultimately becomes a church state power just like the first beast; in this manner making an image of the first beast.

It is then this church state union, or image to the beast, which enforces the mark of the first beast.

I recommend the following resource for more study into the details of this prophecy: https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/study-guide/e/4998/t/the-usa-in-bible-prophecy

Answer (score 0):

No specific denomination was requested, but here is one interpretation.

The first beast of Revelation 13 represents a powerful political/military force, such as what the European Union is now becoming under Germany's leadership, and its extremely charismatic leader.

The second beast represents a powerful religious authority, such as a Pope, that is also extremely charismatic and supports this political power, encouraging everyone to go along with it.  He appears like a lamb (Christ), but speaks like a dragon (Satan).

With each other's support, the two leaders become an unstoppable force, each one directed by Satan.

In Deuteronomy 6:8, the Israelites are told "*And thou shalt bind them* [God's words] *for a sign upon thine hand, and they shall be as frontlets between thine eyes.*", which many Jews today take literally by actually tying [tefillin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin#How_to_put_on_tefillin) to their heads and hands while praying.

But this directive, *given by the second beast and enforced by the first*, could also be considered metaphorically, with the head representing thought and the hand representing action (elsewhere "heart" is used to represent emotions and feelings).

The mark on the right hand or forehead need not be literal, any more than Deuteronomy 6:8 is.  It could represent the way people are expected to think and act.  People that don't behave in the prescribed manner will be shunned or persecuted by society.  [Some suggest](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/beyond-today-magazine/bible-prophecy-and-you-the-beast-the-false-prophet-and-the-antichrist) that it might even be which day of the week one considers to be the day of rest.

Answer (score 0):

The mark of the beast is the antithesis of the mark placed on the elect Jews, chosen to be spared in the coming onslaught of the Romans:

> [Ezekiel 9:1 KJV]
> He cried also in mine ears with a loud voice, saying, Cause them that have charge over the city to draw near, even every man with his destroying weapon in his hand.
> [Ezekiel 9:2 KJV]
> And, behold, six men came from the way of the higher gate, which lieth toward the north, and every man a slaughter weapon in his hand; and **one man among them was clothed with linen, with a writer's inkhorn by his side**: and they went in, and stood beside the brasen altar.
> [Ezekiel 9:3 KJV]
> And the glory of the God of Israel was gone up from the cherub, whereupon he was, to the threshold of the house. And **he called to the man clothed with linen, which had the writer's inkhorn by his side**;
> [Ezekiel 9:4 KJV]
> And the LORD said unto him, **Go through the midst of the city, through the midst of Jerusalem, and set a mark upon the foreheads of the men that sigh and that cry for all the abominations that be done in the midst thereof**.
> [Ezekiel 9:5 KJV]
> And to the others he said in mine hearing, Go ye after him through the city, and smite: let not your eye spare, neither have ye pity:
> [Ezekiel 9:6 KJV]
> **Slay utterly old and young, both maids, and little children, and women: but come not near any man upon whom is the mark; and begin at my sanctuary**. Then they began at the ancient men which were before the house.
> [Ezekiel 9:7 KJV]
> And he said unto them, Defile the house, and fill the courts with the slain: go ye forth. And they went forth, and slew in the city.
> [Ezekiel 9:8 KJV]
> And it came to pass, while they were slaying them, and I was left, that I fell upon my face, and cried, and said, Ah Lord GOD! wilt thou destroy all the residue of Israel in thy pouring out of thy fury upon Jerusalem?
> [Ezekiel 9:9 KJV]
> Then said he unto me, The iniquity of the house of Israel and Judah is exceeding great, and the land is full of blood, and the city full of perverseness: for they say, The LORD hath forsaken the earth, and the LORD seeth not.
> [Ezekiel 9:10 KJV]
> And as for me also, mine eye shall not spare, neither will I have pity, but I will recompense their way upon their head.
> [Ezekiel 9:11 KJV]
> And, behold, **the man clothed with linen, which had the inkhorn by his side, reported the matter, saying, I have done as thou hast commanded me**.

Whereas confession of allegiance is the mark of salvation, denial of Jesus as Christ and Lord is what allows you to buy and sell in Rome. The [Roman official Pliny wrote to his fellow official for advice on how to handle Christians](http://www.attalus.org/old/pliny10b.html#96). He hated to see so many exemplary Romans being killed off simply because they won't deny Christ:

> To Trajan.
>
> It is my custom, Sir, to refer to you in all cases where I do not feel sure, for who can better direct my doubts or inform my ignorance? I have never been present at any legal examination of the Christians, and I do not know, therefore, what are the usual penalties passed upon them, or the limits of those penalties, or how searching an inquiry should be made. I have hesitated a great deal in considering whether any distinctions should be drawn according to the ages of the accused; whether the weak should be punished as severely as the more robust; whether if they renounce their faith they should be pardoned, or whether the man who has once been a Christian should gain nothing by recanting; whether the name itself, even though otherwise innocent of crime, should be punished, or only the crimes that gather round it.
>
> In the meantime, **this is the plan which I have adopted in the case of those Christians who have been brought before me. I ask them whether they are Christians; if they say yes, then I repeat the question a second and a third time, warning them of the penalties it entails, and if they still persist, I order them to be taken away to prison.** For I do not doubt that, whatever the character of the crime may be which they confess, their pertinacity and inflexible obstinacy certainly ought to be punished. *   There were others who showed similar mad folly whom I reserved to be sent to Rome, as they were Roman citizens. **   Subsequently, as is usually the way, the very fact of my taking up this question led to a great increase of accusations, and a variety of cases were brought before me. A pamphlet was issued anonymously, containing the names of a number of people. Those who denied that they were or had been Christians and called upon the gods in the usual formula, reciting the words after me, those who offered incense and wine before your image, which I had given orders to be brought forward for this purpose, together with the statues of the deities - all such I considered should be discharged, especially as they cursed the name of Christ, which, it is said, those who are really Christians cannot be induced to do. Others, whose names were given me by an informer, first said that they were Christians and afterwards denied it, declaring that they had been but were so no longer, some of them having recanted many years before, and more than one so long as twenty years back. They all worshipped your image and the statues of the deities, and cursed the name of Christ. But they declared that the sum of their guilt or their error only amounted to this, that on a stated day they had been accustomed to meet before daybreak and to recite a hymn among themselves to Christ, as though he were a god, and that so far from binding themselves by oath to commit any crime, their oath was to abstain from theft, robbery, adultery, and from breach of faith, and not to deny trust money placed in their keeping when called upon to deliver it. When this ceremony was concluded, it had been their custom to depart and meet again to take food, but it was of no special character and quite harmless, and they had ceased this practice after the edict in which, in accordance with your orders, I had forbidden all secret societies. †   I thought it the more necessary, therefore, to find out what truth there was in these statements by submitting two women, who were called deaconesses, to the torture, but I found nothing but a debased superstition carried to great lengths. So I postponed my examination, and immediately consulted you. The matter seems to me worthy of your consideration, especially as there are so many people involved in the danger. Many persons of all ages, and of both sexes alike, are being brought into peril of their lives by their accusers, and the process will go on. For the contagion of this superstition has spread not only through the free cities, but into the villages and the rural districts, and yet it seems to me that it can be checked and set right. It is beyond doubt that the temples, which have been almost deserted, are beginning again to be thronged with worshippers, that the sacred rites which have for a long time been allowed to lapse are now being renewed, and that the food for the sacrificial victims is once more finding a sale, whereas, up to recently, a buyer was hardly to be found. From this it is easy to infer what vast numbers of people might be reclaimed, if only they were given an opportunity of repentance.
>
> (*)   Pliny leaves it unclear whether the Christians were accused of a specific crime; it seems that to confess to being Christian was considered sufficient proof of guilt.
>
> (**)   Except by special delegation of the Emperor's own legal powers, no provincial governor had power to inflict the death penalty on a Roman citizen, but must allow him to take his trial at Rome.
>
> (†)   Or 'political societies'. The same word {hetaeriae} is used in relation to a guild of firemen, in letter 34 of this book.

Note: The words "to prison" are not original. I think there is a strong case to be made that he meant, "to death".

The response Pliny received from his compatriot said that he was handling the situation as appropriate for Roman rule:

> [97] L   Trajan to Pliny.
>
> You have adopted the proper course, my dear Pliny, in examining into the cases of those who have been denounced to you as Christians, for no hard and fast rule can be laid down to meet a question of such wide extent. The Christians are not to be hunted out ; if they are brought before you and the offence is proved, they are to be punished, but with this reservation - that if any one denies that he is a Christian and makes it clear that he is not, by offering prayers to our deities, then he is to be pardoned because of his recantation, however suspicious his past conduct may have been.** *   But pamphlets published anonymously must not carry any weight whatever, no matter what the charge may be, for they are not only a precedent of the very worst type, but they are not in consonance with the spirit of our age.
>
> (*)   For an early Christian reaction to Trajan's decision, see Tertullian's 'Apology', chapter 2 (written in about 197 A.D.).

Is it not possible or even likely that the "mark of the beast" was denial of Christ?

Answer (score 0):

### Who Causeth?

To simplify the question, "Who causeth all..." one merely has to look at the previous verses,

> **"And I beheld another beast coming up out of the earth; and he had two
>   horns like a lamb, and he spake as a dragon.
>   12 And he *exerciseth* all the power of the first beast before him, and
>   *causeth* the earth and them which dwell therein to worship the first
>   beast, whose deadly wound was healed".**(Rev. 13:11-12)

The "one" doing the causing is the 2nd Beast; the image the 2nd Beast breathes 'life' into is also "caused" by him. Since he is the "motivator" of all that is happening, "he" is the subject of verses 11-16.

### Identifying the Beast of the Earth

In deciphering who the "Beast of the Earth" is, we must review the 4 Basic Hermeneutics of eschatology: Preterist, Idealist, Historicist, and Futurist/Dispensationalist. Each one has a different answer, depending on which hermeneutic you use.

An Idealist view would state that there is no exact interpretation of a specific person or time, but a contest between the forces of darkness and light. Matthew Henry's Full Commentary likens this beast to Papal Authority, with the 2 horns being "ecclesial and secular". Of course there is no way to verify this, but if you accept the viewpoint that "Rome" is the 1st Beast, then you follow with the Roman Catholic Church as being the 2nd.

The Problem with this interpretation is with Rev. 17:8(KJV),

> **"The beast that thou sawest was, and is not; and shall ascend out of
>   the bottomless pit, and go into perdition:"**

Rome, the "kingdom" at the time of John, was NOT the Beast; the angel told John this truth. So any "Idealist" interpretation that would categorize that would be false.

The next view is more specific, but easier to refute: the Preterist Hermeneutic. To understand the Presterist Hermeneutic, you must agree that all(or almost all) prophecy was fulfilled by 70AD, the date of the Destruction of the Temple in Jerusalem. Preterism is very clear about Nero Caesar as being the "Beast" but gets murky when describing the High Priest at the time of the Destruction of the Temple, as "The Beast of the Earth", as there is little historical validity to the claim, and furthermore, nothing "miraculous" is attributed to him.

The Main Objection to this Hermeneutic is John wrote Revelations in 95AD, so it would be antithetical to say in Rev. 1:1(KJV)," ***things which must shortly come to pass***" They counter with numerous arguments, but church Historians, including Irenaeus, state John's exile at Patmos was during the time of Domitian (81-96AD), which was clearly after time of the Temple Destruction.

The next hermeneutic to review is the Futurist/Dispensational. The main consideration of this hermeneutic is it points to a "future" fulfillment of all prophetic activity, usually starting with Chapter 4 of Revelations, although Dispensationalists agree that the "man-child" of Rev. 12:5 is Christ; Futurists have another interpretation. Most Futurists/Dispensationalists concur that the "Beast of the Earth" is an unholy alliance between a world government leader(Antichrist), and apostate religious leader(False Prophet) who would seek to impose their will on mankind during the last 7 years before Christ's Return to Earth.

The vast majority identify the False Prophet as being the "Roman Catholic Church", in some future apostate role, and again, it can't be Rome as was pointed out with the Idealist Hermeneutic.

### Historicist View

The last hermeneutic, the Historicist, is the one most fraught with danger, as it has been the most misused of all the hermeneutics. A Historicist View takes the entire view of history in looking for fulfillment of biblical prophecy; it sees direct fulfillment, unlike the Idealist View, and it isn't confined to the 70AD cutoff, like Preterism, or the last 7 years, like Futurism or Dispensationalism.

The most frequent cause of misuse is identifying the person of the Antichrist; Martin Luther, in 1519 he called Pope Leo X "the Antichrist", to which Pope Leo promptly repaid him his insult. Earlier, when the Holy Roman Emperor Fredrick II(1194-1250) rebuffed Pope Gregory IX's request for a Crusade, the later called him "Antichrist", and this title was carried on by Innocent IV, Gregory's successor. This caused Fredrick II to hire a theologian who proclaimed that "666 spelled the name of Innocent IV, and therefore there was no doubt that Innocent IV was the "true" Antichrist." Neither instances could be rightly claimed, however, as again, the Antichrist is not Roman.

The Historicist View takes in the full spectrum of history, and I believe, when rightly applied, provides the best Hermeneutic in understanding the text.

The word "causeth" appears in verses 12 and 16; in both instances it indicates a period of time rather than a precise moment of time, in which it would be virtually impossible to mark everyone on earth. This "causeth" explains how over a period of time the "Beast of the Earth" gets everyone to worship the Antichrist(willingly), and over a period of time gets everyone "marked", so that they can neither buy nor sell apart from their association with the Antichrist. Since Futurism "confines" this activity to the last 7 years(Dispensationalists claim the "elect" will be raptured, and therefore unaffected), it puts an extreme historical strain on society being in agreement and willingly yielding to a process which by the maximum can only last 7 years.

But what if the Antichrist "appears" earlier in time, and then the False Prophet makes his appearance also, with ample amount of time to "boil the frog"(ie: give society enough time to acquiesce the demands of the Beast and Antichrist). Life would be considered "normal" when it is every bit abnormal, but society is used to the transition, and doesn't oppose the gradual transition. This interpretation lies within the domains of Historicism, and in my view is the most accurate.

### Translating the Symbolism

In order to correctly identify the "Beast of the Earth" we have to translate the Figurative language regarding it.

This "Beast" arises out of the earth, as opposed to the "sea", which we know is "**peoples, multitudes, nations, tongues**"(Rev. 17:15 KJV). Since the Context of the 1st Beast is Figurative, the Context of the 2nd Beast is also Figurative, meaning that this "Beast" doesn't literally arise out of the ground, but is associated with that which is empirical: or of the 5 Senses. It's "Dominion" comes this "empirical knowledge", or "earthly knowledge"which one may obtain by using their 5 senses(seeing, tasting, touching, feeling, smelling), in other words, measurable phenomenon, as opposed to "spiritual" phenomenon. It has 2 horns "**like a lamb**", meaning that it appears to be gentle and submissive in nature, yet "**spoke as a dragon**", which indicates his authority comes from Satan, and dare anyone resist or challenge it.

This Beast also works "miracles" in the sight of man, and "**calling down fire from Heaven on the earth in the sight of man**" is a direct reference to Elijah's "calling down fire from Heaven in the sight of men"(1 Kings 18:38, KJV),

> **Hear me, O LORD, hear me, that this people may know that thou art the
>   LORD God, and that thou hast turned their heart back again.
>   38 Then the fire of the LORD fell, and consumed the burnt sacrifice,
>   and the wood, and the stones, and the dust, and licked up the water
>   that was in the trench**.

The "Fire from Heaven" is God's Apparent Approval, the "miracles" are seemingly only what God can do, and hold the people powerless in great amazement. Yet it is not in the "Power of God", but the "Power of Man" that these miracles are accomplished; therefore, he causes everyone NOT to worship him, but to worship the 1st Beast, the Antichrist, doing his "miracles" in the "Name" of the 1st Beast.

The 2nd Beast can rightly be called "Science", or "Science Falsely So Called". In 1 Tim. 6:20(KJV), it says,

> **O Timothy, keep that which is committed to thy trust, avoiding profane
>   and vain babblings, and *oppositions of science falsely so called***:

In the Interlinear Version it says, "**ἀντιθέσεις τῆς ψευδωνύμου γνώσεως**", which can be translated as "*antithesis of falsely called knowledge*". This "knowledge" led to discoveries in every arena of man, yet their outcome is not a "Greater Worship of God", but "A greater worship of man". The Scientific Community 'appears' beneficial towards the cause of man, but approves abortion, euthanasia, medical research using live human subjects, stem-cell and genetic experimentation with live babies. We've all witnessed manned space flight; Neal Armstrong's Famous Saying, "One small step for man, one giant step for mankind". These things are done with God's Apparent Approval-yet God is never invoked, or involved in the decision.

Science "creates" the Modern Technological Society which we live in today, and we are all "REQUIRED BY LAW" to submit to the academic standards and knowledge base that scientists have established. It is a requirement for schools to teach "Evolution", it is against the Law in many states to teach "Creation". This same "science" has taught "Racial Purity" in Nazi Germany, 'Proletariat of the People" in Russia, China, and numerous other nations, and "Progressiveism" here, to the point where parents can have their children physically removed from them, if it is found they didn't have certain vaccinations. The "Knowledge" Science receives is from the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil; it may be beneficial, but in the end destructive, as only God knows what is truly good and evil.

### Summary

The one who "causeth" is the 2nd Beast; the Beast of the Earth. Over Time he causeth all the Earth to worship the 1st Beast, the Antichrist. This 2nd Beast can rightly be called "Science", which takes the "miracles of Modern Man", making an 'image' called the "Modern Technological Society", and compelling all men to worship "Man as God", the Antichrist.

Answer (score 0):

Just another explanation of the passage, to add the previous, beautiful replies.
Apocalypse is a live book, meaning that many of its parts are being fulfilled throughout history, until the time all of the book will be fulfilled and Messiah will come again. Adding to that, world rulers like Hitler, who we know was tattooing 666 on the forehead of people in concetration camps, we can see why every so often, more and more interpretations of the nature of beasts are arising, which are really good for the era they are created and until the passing of that era.

Following is my interpretation and I believe it is correct up to the point that this world remains the same to the end of days.
The wornd "Name = Onoma" in  Greek (and other ancient civilisations), is something that actually describes the properties of the barer. John insists that 666 is the name of the beast and it is actually not a parabolical name (onoma anthropou esti = human name it is), meaning that we will actually see and listen this name and that the barer (beast) will not be what it is without this name.

This name in our days, exists only because of consumism. We need it because we constantly keep consuming all the resources around us to the point we cannot find enough from local productions.
 It came up with the bar code since number 6 was the number that would create a 1 to be carried over on to the next scanned item or leave the number as it was if the addition of the binary numbers (bars) wouldn't go over 9. That was because IT specialists, wanted to use the minimum possible digits (memory was expensive during early days), which were 4,1111 going up to number 15, which is more than 9 (3 binary digits can go up to 8).Thus, the barcode back then, could not be suited with another binary number unless a lot of money would be invested to PCs, that would be used especially for scanning labels.

The next beast, is the so called false prophet. He makes all people, rich and poor, kings and slaves, to believe in the other beast the antichrist. Also, John constantly speaks about the image when ever he speaks about this beast.
To me, this makes obvious that, in our current epoch and until things change, this kind of beast, that even predicted twin towers and Trumps election through false prophesies is, the screens. Computer screens, cinema screens, telephone screens, TV screens and all the industry behind them. The ones we use to learn, educate, find out about things that happened, happen or even will happen.

Comment: A beast is an animal. A human animal is a person who acts like an animal. Here the Beast is equated with the three numbers 666. Which is a number that symbolizes man, according to Rev 13:18. Thus, a person can be said tho have a beast mark on the forehead/hand if frequenting the Tower of Babylon. Consequently, God favours mountainless love. However, he is long suffering, not wanting anybody to get lost. Chastity is the keyword here.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

It is the 2nd beast….the earthly-minded false prophet who acts in behalf of the 1st beast (in the false prophet’s preaching of “another Jesus” in order to deceive people)….that causes all to receive a mark in their right hand or in their foreheads to make them captives.

This “mark” is connected to the “image” of the beast.

The “image” is a dogma that we form within our very own minds of what we think is the right and wise thing to do in worshiping God.

The ancient Greek meaning of “dogma” means “what one thinks is right or true”.  We make an image (a carnal commandment) to the beast ….the 1st beast which is “another Jesus”.

> Proverbs 14:12 KJV (12)  **There is a way which seemeth right unto a
>   man, but the end thereof are the ways of death.**

**For example,** suppose I think in my own supposed “wise” mind that we should all worship God on Tuesdays only.

I  will then go find a “church” to attend where what I believe is true (the image) is in their “handwriting of ordinances (dogmas)” and go to worship and  serve it in the company of other like-minded, supposedly “wise” people who are like me.    It makes me a captive.

I will have affirmed this “dogma” and go to where others worship and serve this dogma.  It is “gospel” to do it…but it is “another gospel”…and it is erroneously the way of serving “another Jesus” that is being preached by the 2nd beast (the false prophet).

The false prophet causes all in his congregation of like-minded people to worship and serve this dogma as it is in the “handwriting” of the church’s “statement of beliefs”.  One cannot belong without this affirmation of and the serving of what is in the “handwriting”…the church documents.

One cannot participate without belonging to the system and affirming of its things....the orderly arrangement of the church with all of its laws, statements of beliefs, etc.

Those who do not serve the image (the dogma) are then judged as “evil doers” according to the handwriting of dogmas of which I think is true and wise to keep in my own mind.

Those who do not serve it are “killed” with the sword of the tongue that acts as judge, jury and executioner of others who do not worship and serve my dogma of worshiping on Tuesdays (**for example)**.

Judging another over my own “law” is not doing the law of Christ who commanded us to have love for one another.   There is only One Lawgiver who can save and destroy, so why would I judge another using my own dogma that I keep as “gospel”?

> Revelation 13: KJV (15)  *And he had power to give life unto the image
>   of the beast, that the image of the beast should both speak, **and cause
>   that as many as would not worship the image of the beast should be
>   killed**.*

The mark is the worshipping (in the forehead) and serving (the right hand) of the handwriting of church dogmas of which we are made captive.  It is the serving of the sin via judging others using the dogma of what I think is true and wise in the mind to serve.

> (16)  **And he causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free
>   and bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their
>   foreheads:**

It is the worshiping and serving of the “creature”….the human formation of the image or ordinance put down in the handwriting of dogmas…more than the Creator.

The written dogma is worshiped (revered, adored, venerated in the mind….the mark in the  forehead) and served (the mark in the right hand).

> Romans 1:25 KJV (25)  *Who changed the truth of God into a lie, a**nd
>   worshiped and served the creature more than the Creator**, who is
>   blessed for ever. Amen.*

In vain do they worship Him (the Creator) as they teach for doctrines the commandments of men (the formation/handwriting  of men….of the scribes).  They worship  (forehead) and serve (right hand) the ordinance that marks them in the “church” that they belong to….or rather are made captives of.

> Matthew 15:8-9 KJV (8)  This people draweth nigh unto me with their
>   mouth, and honoureth me with their lips; but their heart is far from
>   me. (9)  **But in vain they do worship me, teaching for doctrines the
>   commandments of men.**

No man might buy or sell except he has this mark…..

> Revelation 13:17 KJV: (17**)  And that no man might buy or sell, save he
>   that had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his
>   name.**

The false teachers of this particular dogma I believe in (Tuesdays only) and of whom I serve when I judge others by it (the pernicious ways of the false teachers I have surrounded myself with) make “merchandise” of me.

I will have “sold” myself to belong to that particular “church” to those who have “bought” me as a slave who gives them money.

> 2 Peter 2:1-3 KJV (1)  *But there were false prophets also among the
>   people, even as there shall be false teachers among you, who privily
>   shall bring in damnable heresies, even denying the Lord that bought
>   them, and bring upon themselves swift destruction. (2)  And many shall
>   follow their pernicious ways; by reason of whom the way of truth shall
>   be evil spoken of. (3)  **And through covetousness shall they with
>   feigned words make merchandise of you:** whose judgment now of a long
>   time lingereth not, and their damnation slumbereth not.*

As it says in Isaiah 52, we have sold ourselves for nothing….but we shall be redeemed without money.   We have been made “captive” by the “mark” that is in the forehead or the right hand to the worshiping and serving of the handwriting of ordinances rather than God's commandment.

> Isaiah 52:1-7 KJV (1)  Awake, awake; put on thy strength, O Zion; put
>   on thy beautiful garments, O Jerusalem, the holy city: for henceforth
>   there shall no more come into thee the uncircumcised and the unclean.
>   (2)  Shake thyself from the dust; arise, and sit down, O Jerusalem:
>   loose thyself from the bands of thy neck, O captive daughter of Zion.
>   (3)  **For thus saith the LORD, Ye have sold yourselves for nought; and
>   ye shall be redeemed without money.** (4)  For thus saith the Lord GOD,
>   My people went down aforetime into Egypt to sojourn there; and the
>   Assyrian oppressed them without cause. (5)  **Now therefore, what have I
>   here, saith the LORD, that my people is taken away for nought?** they
>   that rule over them make them to howl, saith the LORD; and my name
>   continually every day is blasphemed. (6)  Therefore my people shall
>   know my name: therefore they shall know in that day that I am he that
>   doth speak: behold, it is I. (7)  How beautiful upon the mountains are
>   the feet of him that bringeth good tidings, that publisheth peace;
>   that bringeth good tidings of good, that publisheth salvation; that
>   saith unto Zion, Thy God reigneth!

The Lord comes to give us an understanding in the Spirit of Truth…the Living Waters.  He that has no money, come and buy and eat.  Buy wine and milk without money and without price.

> Isaiah 55:1-3 KJV (1)  *Ho, every one that thirsteth, come ye to the
>   waters, **and he that hath no money; come ye, buy, and eat; yea, come,
>   buy wine and milk without money and without price.***

Why spend money for that which is not bread….not being the Bread of Heaven…and does not satisfy our hunger for His knowledge?

> (2)  *W**herefore do ye spend money for that which is not bread? and your
>   labour for that which satisfieth not?** hearken diligently unto me, and
>   eat ye that which is good, and let your soul delight itself in
>   fatness. (3)  Incline your ear, and come unto me: hear, and your soul
>   shall live; and I will make an everlasting covenant with you, even the
>   sure mercies of David.*

The Lord preaches the good news ….to preach deliverance to the “captives”…. who are slaves to the sin (by judging others) in the worshipping and serving  of their “handwriting of dogmas” which are really against us and contrary to us…as a heavy stone that blocks the tomb.

> Luke 4:17-19 KJV (17)  *And there was delivered unto him the book of
>   the prophet Esaias. And when he had opened the book, he found the
>   place where it was written, (18)  The Spirit of the Lord is upon me,
>   because he hath anointed me to preach the gospel to the poor; he hath
>   sent me to heal the brokenhearted, **to preach deliverance to the
>   captives,** and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them
>   that are bruised, (19)  To preach the acceptable year of the Lord.*

The Lord comes to give us His knowledge.... to we who are dead in our sins and the uncircumcision of the flesh as we judge others using the handwriting of church dogmas….of those things which we think are true and are being used to judge others to “hell” for not keeping.  We are divided because of the various handwritings of church dogmas but He will quicken us TOGETHER with Him.

> Colossians 2:13-23 KJV (13)  *And you, being dead in your sins and the
>   uncircumcision of your flesh, hath he quickened together with him,
>   having forgiven you all trespasses;*

He blots the handwritings of ordinances out.  He takes them out of the way….the stone gets rolled away from the tomb.  He nails it to His cross as we are forgiven for our keeping of them. We cannot come together in Him because of the handwritings of the church scribes.

> (14)  *Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us,
>   which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to
>   his cross; (15)  And having spoiled principalities and powers, he made
>   a shew of them openly, triumphing over them in it. (16)  Let no man
>   therefore judge you in meat, or in drink, or in respect of an holyday,
>   or of the new moon, or of the sabbath days: (17)  Which are a shadow
>   of things to come; but the body is of Christ.*

Let no man….the false prophet….defraud you of your reward (the manifestation of the eternal life of Jesus in this mortal body in this earth) in a voluntary humility and worshiping of “angels”….messengers which are the transmissions of men….the handwriting of their messages/dogmas…which are passed down through generations for their congregations to worship and serve.

> (18)  Let no man beguile you of your reward in a voluntary humility
>   and worshipping of angels, intruding into those things which he hath
>   not seen, vainly puffed up by his fleshly mind, (19)  And not holding
>   the Head, from which all the body by joints and bands having
>   nourishment ministered, and knit together, increaseth with the
>   increase of God. (20)  **Wherefore if ye be dead with Christ from the
>   rudiments of the world, why, as though living in the world, are ye
>   subject to ordinances, (21)  (Touch not; taste not; handle not; (22) 
>   Which all are to perish with the using;) after the commandments and
>   doctrines of men?**

The “will worship” starts in our own minds….the making of an image of what we think serves Jesus.   It seems “wise” to go and submit ourselves to a church and the worshiping and serving of it’s handwriting of dogmas of what we think is true and wise to keep.

> (23)  Which things have **indeed a shew of wisdom in will worship,** and
>   humility, and neglecting of the body; not in any honour to the
>   satisfying of the flesh.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 figures of importance who are evil that the Book of Revelation introduces:

First, the Dragon or Satan, that old serpent (Revelation 12:9 …”9And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world…”)  The DRAGON, Satan, is worshipped for giving the beast power Revelation 13:4 ”And they worshipped the dragon which gave power unto the beast…”

Second, the First Beast/little horn in Daniel ch.8/and or Antichrist (Revelation 13:1-8) is a king (Revelation 17:10-12), a world political leader and is one of the HEADS OF THE DRAGON whose deadly wound was healed (Revelation 13:3,12) IS WORSHIPPED along with the dragon (Revelation 13:4), who RECEIVES HIS GREAT AUTHORITY, POWER, AND SEAT from the Dragon who is Satan or the Devil.(Revelation 13:2)

Third, the Second beast rises out of the earth (Revelation 13:11) is like a Lamb yet speaks like a Dragon; the miracles are performed BEFORE THE FIRST BEAST/ANTICHRIST(Revelation 13:14 “ HE HAD POWER TO DO IN THE SIGHT OF THE BEAST”, causing fire to come from heaven (revelation 13:12-15), a religious figure: THE FALSE PROPHET (Revelation 19:20 And the beast was taken, and with him false prophet that wrought miracles before him…”); gives life to an image of the beast

Fourth, the image of the Beast whom the false prophet gave life both to speak and cause (Revelation 13:14-16)

Revelation 13:14 Because of the signs it was given power to perform on behalf of the first beast, it deceived the inhabitants of the earth. It ordered them to set up an image in honor of the beast who was wounded by the sword and yet lived.
15 The second beast was given power to give breath to the image of the first beast, so that the image could speak and cause all who refused to worship the image to be killed.
16 It also forced all people, great and small, rich and poor, free and slave, to receive a mark on their right hands or on their foreheads, 17so that they could not buy or sell unless they had the mark, which is the name of the beast or the number of its name. (NIV)

Revelation 13:14 And deceiveth them that dwell on the earth by the means of those miracles which he had power to do in the sight of the beast; saying to them that dwell on the earth, that they should make an image to the beast, which had the wound by a sword, and did live. 15 And he had power to give life unto the image of the beast, that the image of the beast should both speak, and cause that as many as would not worship the image of the beast should be killed.
The Mark of the Beast
16 And HE CAUSETH ALL, both small and great, rich and poor, free and bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads: 17And that no man might buy or sell, save he that had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his name. (KJV)

To answer the question, the one who will force all to receive the Mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads is the FOURTH FIGURE: THE IMAGE OF THE BEAST.

Verse 15, introduces the IMAGE OF THE BEAST who will BOTH SPEAK and CAUSE many to be put to death for not worshipping the image of the beast; verse 15 says: And he had power to give life unto the image of the beast, that the image of the beast should both speak, and cause that as many as would not worship the image of the beast should be killed.
The one who causes is primarily the iMAGE OF THE BEAST whom the second beast, the false prophet, CAUSES TO COME ALIVE.

The image of the Beast is the one CAUSING BY SPEAKING and FORCES the DEATH OF THOSE WHO WILL NOT WORSHIP HIM (Revelation 13:15) although it is seems the Second Beast gives the instruction for the Image of the Beast; hence, the False Prophet is not the one actually enforcing the mark to be inserted (RIF CHIP) in their hands; yet, still he CAUSES by commanding the IMAGE OF THE BEAST to carry it out: by commanding the Death of others who will not worship the image of the Beast.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no force mentioned in the passage. The effect is for the cause of the image. Not a force. But Satan with craft, words, causing deception and directing a world education system [media] to make a image to himself of a Messiah and deliverer of the world.

Understand how God views the people that worshiped Satan. They are called the dead [Revelation 20 kjv]. Not because Satan physically killed them. But because of Apostasy 2 Thessalians 2. They believed him therefore they died. Those who do not yet worship should be killed as the rest, meaning worship and die. They took the mark. That caused them to die. Those who did not worship the image should be killed, as the rest who took the mark.

Belief in that message marks the mind. The hand symbolizes work, the mind puts it to.  While Satan is one of forces, it's by deception, peace, is the crux of the matter.
Read Revelation 9
It is the mouth that the " fire, smoke, and brimstone issues.
Thus causing hurt. Sticks and stones may break bones, but his words in this case can cause a state of death to one's soul.
His words are as The Dragon for he is. Yet his outward appearance is The Lamb of God, this is of the second beast. Satan at the midway point at the 6th Trump. [ Daniels midst of the week]. Shorted by Christ to five months. But that is getting ahead of the question.

Concerning the Marking:

Notice that everyone who has the mark is killed already. Except, those who do not, have the mark. This passage is in the spiritual figurative sense. Concerning the state of the souls, as Paul said in 1 Corinthians 15:51-53 KJV.

The first beast, the world system is made to speak. Not by force. But by a force or war of words. They're directed to kill those who have not worshiped. This does not imply that they know who does not believe them. Only that, that is the job of the first beast at that point.
To cause spiritual death of all by broadcasting Satan's message.
Once the image hits the mind and they believe, they are marked.

Revelation 13

> 15 And he had power to give life unto the image of the beast, that the image of the beast should both speak, and cause that as many as would not worship the image of the beast should be killed.
>
> 16 And he causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads:

The cause is brought about by the speaking. The effect is the marking aka spiritual death.  So The passage "would not worship the image" can be read as "have not yet worshiped the image".

Christ taught an equivalent teaching, in The Gospels, in Mark 13, Luke 21, Matthew 24 KJV, with the term [paraphrase] "those with child, and, give suck, in those days".

Those with child is the mark in the mind, the give suck, is the hand, nursing the deception of the mind along to others. A once virgin bride no longer, but a whore, given in adultery.
To the ultimate Idolatry.

The Lord Christ addressed Seven Churches in chapters 2 and 3.
He's forewarning of the spiritual state they're in, and the deception to come which they're in jeopardy of.

You'll notice, that Christ mentions that they may think he arrives already, and not expect Him when He does arrive, thus " unexpectedly, they're overtaken by these events.  Idolatry is mentioned. And false teachings they hold which will lead them to Satan at that Time.

Comment: I should add, the first beast is simply the one world political system. Political.
The 2nd Beast Satan himself, Religious. As false Christ. The whole system takes on a religious tone once he reveals himself with his miracles. He directs the system of the first beast to glorify him, that image. Of a world at war, which he brought peace to. But its a total lie. hes hurting mens souls who have not the seal of God in their mind. This truth understood.

Answer (score 0):

**The Number of Man** It should be acknowledged that throughout the Bible, a beast represents a nation or more properly, an Empire, not an individual man. Men, or rather Kings, are represented by heads or horns individually. We should not expect any difference in the book of Revelation.

Knowing this, gives a hint as how to interpret the foreboding  Number. It is *the number of man* (NIV). So when we consider, hermeneutically, the Context of Revelation, and the occupation of Judea by the iron-booted Romans, we are directed to the fact that the first six letters of the Roman numerical system add up to...you guessed it...666!
I = 1
V = 5
X = 10
L = 50
C = 100
D = 500
-----------
666

This clearly evident summation is more readily acceptable than all the attempts by end-time prognosticators to fit some Caesar, some Pope, some Dictator, some political enemy...into a gematria scheme of their choosing!

The Number is the collective number of Man (in this case Roman society) that harasses the Elect of God through persecution, and martyrdom. But they are to be no match for the Lamb and His saints who have *His Father's Name written in their foreheads (14:1).

{For those who have a hard time with the pronouns, "his, he, etc." as referring to a Beast instead of to a single *man*, note that later on in chapter 14, Babylon is also referred to with a pronoun: "she."And yet it is a city (representing an evil nation), not a single lady!}

Answer (score -1):

The "Mark" in the hand or the forehead (for anyone without hands becomes clearer with each passing year.  The world is heading to a "cashless" society. Already some toll roads have made it impossible to pay a "toll" collector.  You need a "pass" on your windscreen to pay a toll or a camera takes your license plate and you are sent a bill plus several dollars surcharge (hint, hint). The goal is to make it uncomfortable to not take these "passes".  The goal is also to make it uncomfortable to not take the VeriChip in your hand between your thumb and index finger. At first people will not be compelled to have the VeriChip or there are a few other patented chips out these. But to not take the chip (which is really a rice grain size glass capsule surrounded by a polyethelene cover) means you will have to conduct business at impossible hours and you will have to pay "special" charges just because you want to use cash. There are already many thousands of people who have taken the VeriChip.  The excuse is that their medical data will be easily accessible.  But the real reason is to control the worlds population. In the US most people have never heard of Cray computers but they make IBM look like amateurs.  The Cray computers are designed to keep track of all communications, all purchases, all individuals, all travelers, all tourists, all habits of people, in short it is the Revelation come true.  All Bible Prophecy are written in the Bible and most maxiamally assuredly they will come true.  If not, they would not be found in the Bible. Anyone who decides to take this  Mark (VeriChip) will not be found in the book of life.  There will be groups of people who have no choice but to take it.  Among them will be members of the military, employees of any government, residents of nursing homes, all prisoners, all newborn children, anyone entering the US from any country, anyone who drives a car or truck, anyone who receives Medicaid, social security payments, Medicare, or receives foodstamps or buys food or drink.  In short unless you live off the land and do not need medical care or never have to travel you will be required to have one of these chips inserted between your thumb and index finger. The use of the "Chip" precedes the "Beast".  The US Government has built what can only be described as camps that are unoccupied.  What is their purpose is anyone's guess. For several years now it has been difficult to purchase small caliber .22 long rifle Rim Fire ammunition through a voluntary agreement among the ammunition manufacturers and the US Government to not manufacture this "low cost" ammunition.  This was due to some misguided idea that it would prevent kids from buying it and taking their 22 rifles to school.  It may have stopped some but the more determined kids bought .223 cartridges and took their "assault" rifles to schools. Whoever turns out to be the "Beast" of Revelation will probably not be revealed until after a third of mankind are killed and only an escalating nuclear exchange will bring that about. The population of the world continues to grow in spite of the number of abortions and birth control measures. The earth is heading toward 9 billion souls. The deaths of 3 Billion souls would be catastrophic enough for a charismatic individual to emerge from the sea of humanity. In the Revelation the Third Angel sounds his Trumpet and the "star" Wormwood falls to earth and kills many men and makes a third of the waters bitter. That star Wormwood was Chernobyl in 1986.  Now we know that no star in the astronomical sense could fall to the earth since stars are so much larger that a planet. But in Revelation there is also a reference to the great red Dragon of old who is Satan who is cast down to the earth and the dragons tail sweeps a third of the stars of heaven down to the earth as well. The prophecies in the Bible are happening with great frequency today.  There have already been a number of times when the US and the Soviet Union almost started a nuclear war.  Its scary how close we have come to destroying each other. But a third of mankind points to countries that have many more souls than the combined total of the US and Russia which do not amount to even one billion.  God is the only one who can see the future and what he has seen is certain to happen.

Comment: Continuing evidence that there is no moderation being done on this site thanks to the upper management is SE